# Метод валидации

Tags: java, массивы, строки

На вход подаётся адрес, к примеру http://robota245.com
Надо проверить его на валидность.
Адрес должен начинаться с названия протокола, допустимые - http:// или https://
www не обязательно
доменная зона должна разделяться точкой, допустимые - com, org, net
другие точки в названии адреса а так же спецсимволы не допускаются.
Надо реализовать без использования регулярных выражений, только при помощи стандартных возможностей класса String.
И я застопорился в самом начале, помогите разобраться.
Не могу сообразить как проверить на начало http:// или https://, пытаюсь перевести в массив char чтобы проверить по символьно, а оно не получается...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
}

public static boolean validate(String address){
    if (address == null){
        return false;
    }
    if (address.isEmpty()){
        return false;
    }

    char[] chars = address.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        if (chars[0] == 'h' && chars[1] == 't' && chars[2] == 't' && chars[3] == 'p'){
            if (chars[4] == ':' && chars[5] == '/' && chars[6] == '/'){

            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    if (address.startsWith("http://") || address.startsWith("https://")) {

    }
```

Советую изучить все методы класса String
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: Неплохо было бы еще сделать trim(address);

Answer (score 0):

Не стоит заморачиваться с регулярными выражениями и проверками строк для валидации URL - используйте для этого специальный класс `java.net.URL`:

```
URL url = new URL("http://...");
```

В случае, если адрес невалидный - будет выброшено исключение, которое можно обработать. Для того, чтобы проверить протокол, нужно сравнить значение `url.getProtocol()` с `http` и `https`.

Comment: Alex Chermenin, надо будет запомнить. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

public class Solution1 {

```
public boolean validate(String address){
    if (address == null || address.isEmpty())
        return false;

    address = address.trim();

    if (!address.startsWith("http://") && !address.startsWith("https://"))
        return false;

    if (!address.endsWith(".com") && !address.endsWith(".net") && !address.endsWith(".org"))
        return false;

    address = address.replaceAll("www.", "");
    address = address.replaceAll("http://", "");
    address = address.replaceAll("https://", "");
    address = address.replaceAll(".com", "");
    address = address.replaceAll(".net", "");
    address = address.replaceAll(".org", "");

    return chek(address);
}

private boolean chek(String body){
    char[] chars = body.trim().toCharArray();
    for (char c : chars) {
        if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(c)){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

}